# upgrading docker compose version in ubuntu linux

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker

my system os is **ubuntu** ,present **docker-compose version was 1.25** but imported python-django web app has compose-file with version **was 3.9.** how to **upgrade** my **system docker-compose version** so that i can execute the web app

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your Ubuntu version, but generally you can update `docker-compose` by installing the newest possible version as it's described in [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose-on-linux-systems).

```
$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 -R /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`